# Use case of Google GSI, google Signin, get google profile data to fill new register information

Tags: google-signin

I am considering using google signin feature in my site. Because I am myself ending using it a lot on the sites I visit. I am implementing it on my website. My problem is that my registration flow is not one way. I can have several types of users. So I cannot just have a sign up button that the user clicks and he is a registered user.

I was thinking about putting a google sign in button on the bottom of each type registration form. autocomplete of the form fields with the user google profile info, name, email, telephone and etc. and create a register on my database. When when the user visits my site it can click on the google sign up button to login, I would get the email from GSI and login the user on my site. Is that something viable. excuse me but it's the first time I implement this type of feature.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can give [Integration considerations](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/integrate) page a read on Sign in with Google button and/or One Tap. It is quite lengthy, but I think it would help you evaluate if Sign In with Google SDK is right for your site.